# What is the best way to solve `EntityAlreadyExists` error in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I am using `terraform v0.12.6` and I run into many errors like:

```
Error: Error creating Security Group: InvalidGroup.Duplicate: The security group 'security-search-populate' already exists for VPC 'vpc-003e06e33a87c22f5'
    status code: 400, request id: 82acdc81-c324-4672-b9fe-531eb8283ed3

Error: Error creating IAM Role PopulateTaskRole: EntityAlreadyExists: Role with name PopulateTaskRole already exists.
    status code: 409, request id: 49aac94c-d52b-11e9-a535-c19e5ed20660
```

I know I can resolve them by deleting these resources from AWS but I wonder whether there is a better solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the existing resources are already in terraform in another module or workspace, then I would not import any of those resources since resources should be managed by a single state, not multiple.

If the existing resources are not managed anywhere else in terraform, then it should be imported into terraform.

You'll need to find the security group id of `security-search-populate` security group.

```
aws ec2 describe-security-groups \
    --group-names security-search-populate \
    --query 'SecurityGroups[].GroupId' \
    --output text
```

Let's say the sg id is `sg-903004f8`. Import [security group](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/security_group.html#import) to terraform resource `aws_security_group.elb_sg` using your `dev` profile.

```
AWS_PROFILE=dev terraform import aws_security_group.elb_sg sg-903004f8
```

To import [IAM role](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role.html#import) `PopulateTaskRole` to terraform resource `aws_iam_role.developer` using your `dev` profile.

```
AWS_PROFILE=dev terraform import aws_iam_role.developer PopulateTaskRole
```

After these are imported, you can do a targeted terraform plan to see the differences between what's in source controlled terraform and what's upstream in AWS

```bash
AWS_PROFILE=dev terraform plan \
  -target aws_security_group.elb_sg \
  -target aws_iam_role.developer
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wonder where I can find what to be imported. Like `aws_security_group.elb_sg`?

Comment: If you do a `terraform plan`, you can see what resources are attempted to be created. Find the security group that has the name `security-search-populate` and that will be what should be imported. If you post your plan in a gist, it would be possible to determine the exact import commands.

Comment: Are you sure setting `AWS_PROFILE=dev` would work for `terraform import`?

I thought it'd work but turned out I had to change my profile in a separate command.

Answer (score 9):

Change property "name" to "name_prefix" solved to me, and doesn't duplicate any roles and/or policies.

Comment: adding name_prefix and removing it after creation worked for me but why? this kind of undocumented behaviours trigger me so much

Comment: This behavior is caused by  "create before destroy" rule. If you try to create  with same "name" (property) TF gives you duplicate error. When you use "name_prefix" firsr TF create a new one with different suffix and after that destroys the old one.

Comment: I had to go through this. Terrible experience. Thanks @FvSoares

Answer (score -2):

In my case i realised this is not an issue with Terraform. i found the i had some AWS ACCESS key environment variables hanging around in printenv which were different than what i had in my awscli configure statement,

terrafrom was prefering the environment variable (the ones in printenv over the aws config and credential files generated by aws configuration command.