# How to share enviroment-agnostic resources between projects that have separate tfstate files?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Background:

I have a shared module called "releases". releases contains the following resources:

- aws_s3_bucket.my_deployment_bucket
- aws_iam_role.my_role
- aws_iam_role_policy.my_role_policy
- aws_iam_instance_profile.my_instance_profile

These resources are used by ec2 instances belonging to an ASG to pull code deployments when they provision themselves. The release resources are created once and will rarely/never change. This module is one of a handful used inside an environment-specific project (qa-static) that has it's own tfstate file in AWS.

Fast Forward: It's now time to create a "prd-static" project. This project wants to re-use the environment agnostic AWS resources defined in the releases module. prd-static is basically a copy of qa with beefed up configuration for the database and cache server, etc.

The Problem:
prd-static sees the environment-agnostic AWS resources defined in the "releases" module as new resources that don't exist in AWS yet. An init and plan call shows that it wants to create these from scratch. It makes sense to me since prd-static has it's own tfstate - and tfstate is essentially the system-of-record - that terraform doesn't know that no changes should be applied. But, ideally terraform would use AWS as the source of truth for existing resources and their configuration.

If we try to apply the plan as is, the prd-static project just bombs out with an Entity Already Exists error. Leading me to this post:

[what is the best way to solve EntityAlreadyExists error in terraform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57903408/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-entityalreadyexists-error-in-terraform)

^-- logically I could import these resources into the tfstate file for prd-static and be on my merry way. Then, both projects know about the resources and in theory would only apply updates if the configuration had changed. I was able to import the bucket and the role and then re-run the plan.

Now terraform wants to delete the s3 bucket and recreate the role. That's weird - and not at all what I wanted to do.

TLDR: It appears that while modules like to be shared, modules that create single re-usable resources (like an S3 bucket) really don't want to be shared. It looks like I need to pull the environment-agnostic static resources module into it's own *project* with it's own tfstate that can be used independently rather than try and share the releases module across environments. Environment-specific stuff that depend on the release resources can reference them via their outputs in my build-process.

1. Should I be able to define a resource in a module, like an S3 bucket where the same instance is used across terraform projects that each have their own tfstate file (remote state in S3). Because I cannot.
2. If I really shouldn't be able to do this is the correct approach to extract the single instance stuff into its own project and depend on the outputs?

Comment: You'll need to refer to the remote state if you'd like to refer to shared resources. I'd deploy shared resources in a "main"/a project. Other projects can then refer to it's state while not necessarily able to modify the main resources.

Comment: @pijemcolu - I think that makes sense. In the short term, leaving it out of the "prd-static" module unblocks me. I'm a little fearful of the surgery that will have to be done to terraform mv the resources to a different state file extracted for these shared resources.